# Php array value to keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hi let's say I have this array

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "name|a-z+"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "id|0-9+"
}
```

Now I want a new array (or the same if possible) to be like this:

```
array(2) {
  [name]=>
  string(4) "a-z+"
  [id]=>
  string(4) "0-9+"
}
```

I think the solution implies explode and array_combine, but I am not good enough, can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   function convert_my_array($arr){
       $out = array();
       foreach($arr as $obj){
            $data = explode("|", $obj);
            $out[$data[0]] = $data[1];
       }
       return $out;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the original array called $array here, loop through it set the values to what you want.

```
$newarray = array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$val) {
       list($one, $two) = explode('|', $val);
       $newarray[$one] = $two;
}
```

Comment: I believe you mean $array[$one] = $two, though I would suggest using a different variable, not $array, since the new entries will append to the existing one and you'll get a combination of the two arrays.

Comment: Then it will not give the same results as the OP wanted. They wanted the keys to be the value of $one (in your example). At least that's what I understand.  --Oh you already updated your answer. Nevermind then. :)

Comment: after your it's exactly the same, if instead I do $array[$one] = $two; then it's right just there are wrong duplicates